# filtering data using parameters

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this command that is working..

```
cat  ~/Desktop/results.json |  jq '.[] | .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult | select(.key.entityKey.key=="39583746-39747586") | .lifeCycleState '
```

I want to pass the entity key as variable , tried the below ones ,but none seems to work-

```
enkey="39583746-39747586"

cat  ~/Desktop/results.json |  jq '.[] | .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult | select(.key.entityKey.key=="""${enkey}""") | .lifeCycleState '

cat  ~/Desktop/results.json |  jq '.[] | .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult | select(.key.entityKey.key=="${enkey}") | .lifeCycleState '
```

Comment: Single quotes preserve everything inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to use extra parameters in your filters, use the `--arg` option to pass them in.  Don't rely on the shell to insert it into your filter string, keep that separate.

```
jq --arg key "$enkey" '.[] |
  .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult |
  select(.key.entityKey.key == $key) |
  .lifeCycleState' ~/Desktop/results.json
```

Comment: bonus points for implicitly addressing [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)

Comment: one follow up question, this breaks when I change it to curl,                 curl http://localhost:3000/results.json | jq --arg key "$enkey" '.[] |
  .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult |
  select(.key.entityKey.key == $key) |
  .lifeCycleState'  does not return anything.,while the above one that read from file works, both have the same json. Am i doing something wrong here? thanks

Comment: @msreekm: I'm not sure why it would be different.  Try removing the last bits of the filter one at a time until you get a result, then verify that what's left is what you expect.  Otherwise, the only thing I could think of is the curl call isn't returning anything or your `enkey` is not set to a key that exists.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I tried removing the sleect filter and confirmed that the curl is returning the same json and enkey has value that exist in json. not sure what is happening.

Comment: got it working ,it was some case sensitive naming issue,thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
  jq '.[] | .environmentStatuses[].deploymentResult |
  select(.key.entityKey.key == "'$key'") |
  .lifeCycleState' ~/Desktop/results.json
```

`--arg` does not works as expected ...

Comment: Given that [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30770499/2) indicates otherwise, why do you write `--arg` does not work as expected?